# Loop through the children of an element in a AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem - I've forgotten how to code! I have an angularJS directive that is on a parent wrapper tag (a DIV) and in my directive I wish to loop through the children (first Child DIVs). I have the following

```
<div data-check-attributes>
  <div data-ng-repeat="user in Users" data-id="{{ user.ID }}" data-ng-click="doSomething(user.ID)" data-new="{{ user.newUser }}" class="">
    <div> {{ user.userName }} </div>
    <div> {{ user.userAge }} </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now in my directive I wish to loop through the first child divs (there could be many of these, but I am seeing 10 users in my loaded view) and perform certain checks and modifications in my directive, using the data attributes, the $location object and potentially many more... however I can't remember how to loop through the first child divs, I seem to get errors with everything I tried... so far I have this, which doesn't work! In the example below I just want to write the data-id of the first child nodes to the console

```
.directive('checkAttributes', function ($location) {
        return{
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element) {

            // will use $location later

                console.log(angular.element(element)[0]);  // this outputs the HTML
                console.log(angular.element(element)[0].children().length); // this errors, TypeError: object is not a function

                for (var i = 0; i < angular.element(element)[0].children.length; i++) {
                    console.log(angular.element(element)[0].children[i].getAttribute('data-id'));
                }

            }
        };
    });
```

I'm confused... please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are trying to access [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) property of the HTMLElement then you should read it like property.

Another thing is that `element` is already an instance of `angular.element` so no need to wrap it again:

```
console.log(element[0]);  // DOM element
console.log(element[0].children.length);
```

However there is a set of convenience methods [`angular.element`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) object provides. Those methods replicate some of the jQuery's methods, including [`$.fn.children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method. In this case alternatively you can do

```
console.log(element);  // angular.element instance
console.log(element.children().length);
```

And finally, there is one more caveat: `ngRepeat` will render its elements *after* your custom directive, so you can't access `children` collection yet. Simplest fix is to wrap your code into `$timeout` service, which will execute your logic in the next digest cycle, guaranteed after `ngRepeat` is complete:

```
app.directive('checkAttributes', function($location, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {

            // will use $location later
            $timeout(function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < element[0].children.length; i++) {
                    console.log(element[0].children[i].getAttribute('data-id'));
                }
            });

        }
    };
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/oEOSY2e2E0mmLDQOHbff?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, That's great, but I'm still unsure how I can select or check the attribute of each child Div

Comment: That's great thanks... I really need to brush up on my directives and jqLite